# setAttribute smooth transition

Tags: javascript, svg

I trying to recreate this smil animation with pure javascript

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 600 600">
<path id="foo" d="M10 10 C 20 20, 40 20, 50 10" stroke="black" fill="black">
  <animate
       attributeName="d"  to="M500 500 C 20 20, 40 20, 50 10"
       dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </path>
</svg>
```

The problem here is when I use setAttribute to recreate the animation on click
the animation is sudden

```
var path = document.getElementById('foo');
path.addEventListener("click", function(){path.setAttribute('d','M500 500 C 20 20, 40 20, 50 10');});
```

and I can't figure out how to make it smooth like the smil
Is there a way to make it in pure js ?

Answer (score 1):

You can begin an animation on a click event.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 600 600">
<path id="foo" d="M10 10 C 20 20, 40 20, 50 10" stroke="black" fill="black">
  <animate
       attributeName="d"  to="M500 500 C 20 20, 40 20, 50 10"
       dur="5s" begin="0s;foo.click" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Yes Robert I know but I wonder if the same animation can be done with pure javascript without using smil and have this smooth effect.

Comment: call beginElement() on the animation element.

Comment: From what I've understand The beginElement doesn't recreate the animation it allow to trigger an animation on demand

Comment: Then I really don't understand what you want. Best ask another question.

Comment: I want to know if it's possible to recreate the smil animation which allow to animate the path from d="M10 10 C 20 20, 40 20, 50 10" to "M500 500 C 20 20, 40 20, 50 10" with javascript. I can change these value from one to another with setattribute but I can have the smooth transition that i have with smil. So my question is : is it possible to have the smooth transition of smil animation with javascript

Comment: My big question; Why do you want to replace the native/optimized animation (SMIL) with a constructed one (JS) where you have to calc all tweens yourself (or use an animation library)?

Comment: @soniamaklouf sure you'd use beginElement() on the animation to reset it as per my first comment.